# horizontal menu with different background image for each li

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, menu, navigation

I am looking for nested menu which can have different background images , below is the code which does everything , display subnodes with different color when hovered , but i want a different background image for each link and a separate image for sub nodes. Currently it works using colors. (The size of each image for the links will be different)

```
 <div class="TopMenu"> 
    <ul class="myMenu"> 
        <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="About-Us.aspx">About us</a></li> 
        <li><a href="Products-For-Sale.aspx">For sale</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Bedsheets-For-Sale.aspx">Bedsheets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Rugs-For-Sale.aspx">Rugs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Accessories-For-Sale.aspx">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li> 

        <li><a href="News.aspx">News</a></li> 
        <li><a href="Services.aspx">Services</a></li> 

    </ul> 
 </div><!--TopMenu--> 

/*style the main menu*/
  #header .myMenu {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
position:absolute;
 z-index:300;
 left:28px;
 top:108px;
 width:952px;
   }

#header .myMenu li
{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  background-color: #4dafde;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  }

 #header .myMenu li a:link, .myMenu li a:visited
{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #4dafde;
padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 2em;
margin: 0 0 0 0;

}

#header .myMenu li a:hover {
background-color: #A4D6EE;
}



/*style the sub menu*/
#header .myMenu li ul
  {
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #4dafde;
}

#header .myMenu li ul li {
display:inline;
float:none;
 }

#header .myMenu li ul li a:link, .myMenu li ul li a:visited
{
display:block;
width: auto;
text-decoration: none;

 }

  #header .myMenu li ul li a:hover
 {
background-color: #A4D6EE !important;
 }
```

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Thnx

Comment: Using increasingly longer nested selectors for each menu item will make it incredibly hard to maintain. What if you want to go back and change the color/image of the 5th element in the menu in 3 months. How do you find which selector it is in the css? You can use much more precise selectors, as described in the answer below.

Comment: but the nth child has no support in IE 7, 8. Otherwise it would be a great thing to try : something like ul li:nth-child(n+1) { background-image: url('/images/01.png'); }

Comment: So add a separate class or id to each element. That's a cleaner and more maintainable solution anyway. E.g. you won't have to look at the HTML to know what changing the CSS will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll either have to:
A: Add a unique ID to each LI, then in your CSS, add a background image for that LI
B: Use the CSS3 selector :nth-child to select the LI, then apply the background image that way.

Comment: css3 selector compatible wid all browsers , coz i use css3 is my previous websites which failed the ui test in IE 6,7

Comment: but the nth child has no support in IE 7, 8. Otherwise it would be a great thing to try : something like ul li:nth-child(n+1) {
  background-image: url('/images/01.png');
}

Comment: css3 selectors are not compatible with all browsers - specifically anything less than IE9. You can, however, add support for those browsers, using a JavaScript library called "Selectivizr": http://selectivizr.com/

Answer (score 2):

You would either have to define the style as `background: #4dafde none no-repeat scroll left middle` then override `background-image` in the `style` attribute of each `<li>`, or you could be a bit craftier: make the `li`s have a fixed width, then apply one background image to the entire `.myMenu` that has the individual images in the right places (bigger file, but with proper web optimisation the difference should be negligeable, even offset by the benefit of one HTTP request over several).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery may be what you're looking for

Css command can be found here.

[css command](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Use nth-child to find certain child elements of the ul parent

[nth-child info](http://You%20could%20also%20use%20nth-child)